# I'm not seeing 'tightly coupled code' as one of the drawbacks of a monolithic application architecture

Tags: microservices, web-services, distributed-system, coupling

One of the most common things I see when discussing pros/cons of microservice vs monolithic architecture is that monolithic applications have, or always trend toward, 'tight coupling.'

To be honest, I'm not seeing why this is true if your developers know how to leverage any standard OO language. If I need a certain part of my application to handle, say, payments, and multiple other parts to interact with the payments system, can I not leverage the abstraction features of the language I'm using (classes, access control, interfaces) to create modularization between different application functions?

For example, if I'm using Java, I could create a 'PaymentsDAO' (data access object), or maybe 'PaymentsClient', which can expose functions that the rest of the code can use to interact with the payments database, etc. If one sub-team in my team wants to work on payments, they can continue to write code in the PaymentsDAO, publish that code to the central repo, etc, while I simply use the DAO's function signatures, which would not change, and continue to write code wherever I need it, right? Where's the coupling? If payments code changes, I don't need to change anything in my code, or understand the changes, to account for that.

Is the only drawback of this 'coupling' that I need to `git pull` more often, since the payments code would need to be in the same deployment as my change, as opposed to a separate deployment, and then consumed over the network through an API call?

To be honest, I'm not seeing a strong case for the 'tight coupling', and I want someone to change my view here because my current team at work is using a microservice architecture :D I'm more certain about the other pros of MSA, like scalability, flexibility of technology stacks across microservices, fault tolerance of a dist system, and less deployment complexity, but I'm still uncertain on coupling.

Comment: An important note: No architecture can save your butt if your devs don't know what they are doing. Even theoretically loose archs can end up a mess of tightly coupled code if you don't take proper care. You _can_ make a loosely coupled monolithic software without a problem if you put in the extra effort. It is just... well, kinda way harder.

Comment: `to create modularization` - Yes, and now that you've done that you don't have a monolithic application any longer.  You have a GUI that wraps a bunch of modules.

Comment: While you can properly modularize a monolith, the suggestion to just have everyone re-use the DAO is already a step into a not properly decoupled monolith ;P Sharing a  DAO across the whole application is typically already considered too tight a coupling, because you expose the explicit data layer to all other components instead of an abstract layer. Have fun changing the data layer and understanding what other components have written in your structures, why and what assumptions they make about the data returned on that level that. A dao should only be shared in its component.

Comment: It depends. How easy would it be for me, who is not a member of your team, to use your payment calculation logic in my app? If it is as easy as using Jackson or Guava then yes, I'd agree you can write your code to be very loosely coupled. If I have to edit your Payment class then your payment class is kind of coupled to your code. Maybe not tightly but it's certainly not loosely coupled

Comment: Some definitions of monolith might include tight coupling as a defining characteristic.

Comment: @J... - that's nonsense. We've been building modular monolithic applications for half a century before microservices hype.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo My point is that "modular monolithic" is a contradiction in terms.  If we disagree on this, then this debate is nothing more than semantics.

Comment: @J... - it absolutelly isn't, and the only way it's contradiction if you use your own made up nonsensical definitions. Monolithic application is not one that is written poorly.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo No, monolithic means intractably indivisible - made of one giant piece that cannot be broken into parts (ie: not modular).  I think I rest my case.

Comment: @J... - well, yeah, that's your own made up definition. For example the entire Linux kernel is one monolith, despite being divided into hundreds (thousands?) of modules.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo No, that's a dictionary definition from the OED.  Like I said.  Semantics.

Comment: @J...- LMAO you use dictionary definition of the word in a specific engineering context? That's like saying "kernel" is an edible part of a nut.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo Well, clearly there is some debate between "monolithic" meaning simply a self-contained application and "monolithic" meaning an application whose internals and architecture are tightly coupled and non-modular.  Just like "kernel" implies a meaning of something fundamental, nucleating from the middle or core, so does monolithic imply, not just a single piece, but an unbreakable, intractable, and indivisible one. When we choose our words poorly then we end up with engineering terms that suggest or imply a meaning we did not intend.  That seems to be what's going on here.  Semantics.

Answer (score 33):

### Why X when you can do Y?

The problem with questions like these is that no one has ever claimed that you can't take the more difficult route if you really want to. People aren't pointing out that the difficult route is impossible, but rather that it is *needlessly* difficult.

So, yes, if you avoid certain approach and instead spend all needed effort making sure things don't go wrong, that inherently means that things aren't going wrong and you didn't need to use that certain approach. But can you really be sure that:

- You're not spending more effort than if you had followed the suggested approach
- You and every other developer will not make any mistakes in avoiding those problems
- You'll be able to recover when you come across such a problem, and not just realize you've painted yourself in a corner?

The odds are not in your favor.

---

### Different types of coupling

There are **degrees** of loose coupling. It's not a binary state. This is not a complete list, but for the purposes of this discussion, some degrees are:

- Level 0 - No abstractions, hardcoded references
- Level 1 - Abstractions (interfaces), but everything in one project
- Level 2 - One solution, separate projects abstractions
- Level 3 - Abstractions are not part of the project but are loaded separately (think NuGet)
- Level 4 - Independently hosted microservices

You're at level 1/2 now. And it avoids some of the more blatant problems with tight coupling, what I tend to refer to as "code coupling". **There are different types of coupling**, and not all of them are related to the code of a specific application. Subsequent levels are going to solve **additional** problems with certain kinds of coupling.

Level 3 moves the abstraction out of the solution, so that it can live its own life. This is the most useful when more than one solution consumes this abstraction, or when the developers of the abstraction are a completely different team from the developers of the main product. Maybe it's a different company team, maybe they're different companies altogether.

You've probably used several third party libraries. How much did you know about their teams, who developed them, or the internals of the library they created? Not much. And that's the point, because the abstraction is so loosely coupled to the end product that you don't even need to know anything (other than its interface) about it anymore.

But level 3 still suffers a specific problem: if the abstraction gets updated, then all of its consumers will have to rebuild (or at the very least re-release) to account for these new changes. This requires an active line of communication, at least one-way (e.g. a third party developer's news feed announcing a patch to fix issues or expand the feature set).

This is what level 4 (microservices) solve. Because it's now an independently deployed application, any published change goes live for **every** consumer at the same time. The consumers don't need to change anything or re-release their own application.
As long as the interface or public URL doesn't change, the two services don't even need to communicate anything about any of their changes.

A very clear example of why this is desirable is e.g. an identity provider.

- Levels 0/1/2 all amount to authorization for this specific application.
- Level 3 makes it possible to standardize identity management across all of the library's consumers, but in the end each consumer is still choosing to update to new versions of the library individually.
- By having this as a microservice (level 4), any changes made to the identity provider (e.g. changed rights, user access, different security protocols) automatically deploy everywhere at the same time, and the developers of the consuming applications don't even need to be kept in the loop at any stage.

Comment: Wanted to note that level 4 is more than just microservices. If we use RPC, OSGi or some other remoting mechanism, there is no need to re-release the calling application either, without needing microservices (but using some other mechanism to do the same). Even within the same application container we can have separate deployments talking to each other, in java world for example using JNDI.

Comment: @eis: I'd consider these as being microservices, just ones that use a different (i.e. non-HTTP) protocol to talk to one another. If it's independently deployable, self-contained, and considered a component (by some description), then it's a microservice. But it's probably a semantical argument.

Comment: Fair enough, don't neccessarily disagree. But I think this is a definition worth mentioning, as I think by microservices most people think about the current, self-contained, http-discussing microservices.

Comment: Not sure L4 solves the problem you mention in L3: "*if the abstraction gets updated, then all of its consumers will have to rebuild*". One of the conditions you set on L4 is "*As long as the interface or public URL doesn't change*", which could equally apply to libraries on L3. If the interface changes, you'll have to re-release whether you're using a library or a microservice. Where L4 changes is that if the **implementation** changes (not the abstraction), then you don't have to re-release (but system-wide libraries can help with that too).

Comment: And you can even have cases where an "L4" service *accidentally* changes its interface simply by upgrading to a newer version of <some serialization package> that has subtle differences in how it translates between internal objects and the on-the-wire format.

Comment: @DavidGelhar API can always evolve and if it need to, so be it. However they're also ways to handle retrocompatibility with consumer that are not up-to-date yet. Consuming different version of a microservice is probably easier than doing it at L3.

Comment: @Bruno: You're pointing out something that's already in the answer. In L3, you have to redeploy regardless of whether it was the interface or the implementation that changes, hence why I didn't bother distinguishing between them at that point. Then in L4, I mention that _as long as the interface or public URL doesn't change_, you don't need to actually redeploy.

Comment: @DavidGelhar: A changed interface is not defined by whether the change was intended or not. A changed interface is, by definition, a changed interface. Whether or not consuming different versions of microservices is easier wholly depends on the implementation of the microservice. You already pointed out an issue where it would _not_ be easier (i.e. an unintentional change to the serialization tool used across the microservice).

Comment: @Flater You don't necessarily have to re-deploy if it's a system library (e.g. .Net upgraded with the system). Also, the notion that you don't have to adapt to implementation changes of the microservice seems a bit idealistic. In practice, even if the interface doesn't change, and change of behaviour (bug fix or bug introduction) in the implementation of the microservice or library may change the behaviour of your app, and require new workarounds or changes too.

Comment: Problems can actually be made worse if the microservice imlementation changes for everyone without telling its users. The benefit of not having to redeploy comes at the cost of possibly unpredictable changes outside your control: there's a trade-off to be made.

Comment: @Bruno: We're arguing over our own imaginary changes. Of course when something breaks in your app because of a change in a dependency, no matter the reason, you have to respond. But the most frequent changes are silent bugfixes or improvements, which don't inherently require consumer action. In L3, they still require redeployment (due to the nature of the dependency being included in the application), in L4 they don't (due to the nature of the dependency living as a remote service). Yes, other examples of L4 exist, but OP specifically comes from a microservice environment so I focused on that.

Comment: How does this play into higher order requirements, like a regulatory compliance structure?  Payment is a regulated industry, but it is not regulated like medical industry, for example, a change in a thirds party micro-service that is not communicated to regulators appropriately may result in serious consequences for the business.  This answer, in my view is specific to the developer side of the stakeholders

Comment: @crasic: Additional considerations are, well, _additional_. The question did not in any way stipulate a regulatory compliance structure, and so this answer didn't account for it either. I'm not in any way suggesting that one _must_ go to the highest level possible or that there are no possible drawbacks from doing so. I'm not sure what you're actually responding to here.

Comment: @Flater I am sorry I wasn't clear and perhaps came across confrontational, but your comment is perfect. My point is basically YMMV.

Comment: So L4 is like L3 but instead of a proper test cycle, you get a call at 3AM on Saturday. Got it!

Comment: @user253751: Or, in another instance, L3 is like L4 but instead of being able to patch the persistent critical failure for everyone, you keep getting emails about failures that would've been avoided if they had just updated to the latest version of the package. But since no one proactively reads the news feed, they only listen when they've already run into and reported issues. L4 is much prefererable in cases such as security patches,where you want to be able to force people to use the newest version. For everything else, an L4 microservice can version its API to allow backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 10):

## Distributed Systems

The problem here is that you're still thinking of this in terms of a single program running on a single machine.

Let's say you have three services:

1. A Payment System.
2. A Background Task that takes 1 hour.
3. A Video Upload Service.

Let's say you build this as a single service and deploy it.  It goes live and starts handling payments, uploading, and background tasks.  Everything works fine, and your code is well structured.

That is, until the problems start...

### Deployment

You find out there is a major problem with the payment system, and you need to change some configuration.  This is a trivial change, and only requires a quick restart.

**Problem:**  A quick restart breaks the background task, you now have to rerun it... delaying results (or even leading to a corrupt state!)

### Scaling

Your service is going viral, you need to ensure you have the resources to handle the load!  You can scale based on CPU or Requests/s.

**Problem:**  The payment system uses little CPU, so needs to be scaled based on Requests/s.  Video uses a lot of CPU (transcode), but few requests... so needs to scale based on CPU.  Your infrastructure only allows you to pick one.

### Diagnostics

A random rare bug is occurring. This breaks everything, including payment - costing the company big time!

**Problem:**  You don't know which service the bug occurs in.  Furthermore... it might be an unexpected result of multiple subsystems interfering.

### Dependancies

You need to upgrade a library to fix a production bug in the Background worker.

**Problem:**  The upload service uses the same library... but the upgraded version breaks it. Fixing one service breaks another.

---

As you can see while programming languages do have tools to help decouple code, that doesn't decouple deployment and execution by itself.  Microservices help to decouple deployment and execution, as well as helping decouple code.

Comment: The payment point is pretty good illustration. We are very often using others' payment services - PayPal, Amazon payments, among many others. The consumption is very much like you'd consume your own microservice. You don't need to change your application if the payment service changes, nor change the payment service if you change your application.

Comment: Some of these are a bit iffy.  Most infrastructure will allow you to scale across multiple dimensions, for example.  (you still potentially lose a bit of efficiency with the monolith vs the split out solution though, as you might have to overprovision)

Or the background task example - that's just a badly designed background task that doesn't pick up where it left off on restarts.

Comment: "Some of these are a bit iffy. " 

@AngusGoldsmith these are all anonymized real examples I've dealt with in production systems.


"Or the background task example - that's just a badly designed background task that doesn't pick up where it left off on restarts."

WIth this monolithic pattern *every* restart restarts *everything*.  So now you have to make sure every single piece of code can be restarted at whim. 

Sometimes code is badly designed - in fact, lots of code is badly designed.  Microservices compartmentalizes failures... monoliths compound them.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Sure, that's a fair point.  Just worth noting those problems aren't intrinsically problems with monoliths, just issues that, as you say, would at least be limited in scope with microservices.

Answer (score 8):

> If I need a certain part of my application to handle, say, payments, and multiple other parts to interact with the payments system, can I not leverage the abstraction features of the language I'm using (classes, access control, interfaces) to create modularization between different application functions?

Not in practice.

The problem is that all of those abstraction features live in the code that developers control. They can change them, ignore them, destroy them. And companies will push developers to cut corners to meet a deadline, or hit some quota. Even if you believe that all engineers will refuse to cut corners to get a promotion, they’ll still screw up. Once you get a dozen or so programmers making a few dozen changes a week, the chance that someone adds coupling somewhere it shouldn’t go increases rapidly over time.

Sure, people can do the same thing with microservices, but it is harder to do; easier to notice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is way easier to mess up with microservices than you're alluding to. Micros are an order of magnitude harder to debug and test, and their development has a whole different set of pitfalls. They are a valuable tool, but _not for everything_ and should not be used as a silver bullet.

Comment: @T.Sar: I don't think that was Telastyn's point. Rather than it's significantly harder for a developer to bypass an abstraction layer when that abstraction is its own hosted microservice, as opposed to when it is e.g. a different project in the same solution. You can quickly (and without much notice) add a project reference where you shouldn't, but that same kind of shortcut is much harder to quickly bang out when you don't even have access to both the source code or the deployed files of the abstraction (as is the case with microservices).

Comment: That's true _if_ you're keeping the microservices in separate solutions, but that's often not the case. More often then not, they are just mangled together into a single super-solution with everything, and have just as much spaghetti as a single mono solution. Microservices don't force you to organize them properly anymore than any other architecture. They just heavily suggest you to do so, but if you'll follow that or not... that's another question entirely.

Comment: @T.Sar - yes, I was only talking about the coupling point. Microservices do add complexity and are not universally applicable. Sure, people can have them in a single repo/solution, but that is uncommon in my experience, easier to enforce programmatically, and a single decision to screw up rather than the continual correct decisions required by class level decoupling,

Comment: @T.Sar the heavy suggestion is basically always the best you can get from prgramming/architecture paradigms. In the end, as a developer you can twist all code to your perverted will. A good architecture will just make some perversions harder. At least for preventing cross-component data access microservices (if they are somewhat worth the name) indeed achieve that - it's way easier to just inject the database connection and wildly modify data of another component in a monolith; as you said, still possible with a microservice but more effort and thus perhaps discouraging enough^^

Answer (score 3):

### What is ‘tight coupling’

Tight coupling means when the components know a lot about what the other does. It does not matter whether they communicate by calling functions, passing interfaces or making HTTP requests—if the other side uses deep understanding of the data, it is tightly coupled, and will have to be adjusted a lot as the project continues.

If the application is developed as one product by one team, it will tend to tight coupling. Even if you make it a bunch of micro-services. Everybody understands what the other parts do and just slapping the logic anywhere is simply easier than creating proper abstractions.

You have to put conscious effort to insert good abstractions to reduce the coupling—and it again does not matter if the abstractions are interfaces, network calls, or on the other hand just views in a database. What matters is that they only expose specific aspect of the problem and hide all the other details.

### Reducing coupling

You can only reduce coupling to the point the problem you are solving itself can be decomposed. Payments probably need to know about the services being paid for all the way until you generate the payment orders to send to the bank. There you have an abstraction, the payment orders are generic, but the code generating them is coupled to other parts of your accounting. And no DAO can change anything on that. As long you need the data, it is coupled.

### Taking advantage of lose coupling

What is an advantage of micro-service architecture is that it can *take advantage* of lose coupling *if and when* you can achieve it.

So you need authentication? If you have a monolithic application in Java, you need a middleware fitting the framework you use—and if it does not fit well, you'll have to adapt it. But if you use micro-services, you just install this other service and it absolutely does not matter that it's implemented in Go.

Then you need to generate the billing information. Hey, that component does the job and we know how to use it because we've used it on that other project already and it totally does not matter that it is a blob of ageing PHP.

And that cloud service that provides nice graphs for the managers? Much easier to integrate in a micro-service architecture again.

So that's the benefit of micro-service architecture with lose coupling—for the functionality that you *can* abstract you can more easily integrate off-the-shelf components, and you have bigger choice of components, because you are not tied to the application server.

Micro-service architecture still has advantages in things like scaling even for components that are tightly coupled, but that is a different question.

### Deployment

> Is the only drawback of this 'coupling' that I need to git pull more often, since the payments code would need to be in the same deployment as my change, as opposed to a separate deployment, and then consumed over the network through an API call?

For most software, you want to be deploying the whole solution as a unit no matter how many components it is split over and how tightly or loosely coupled they are.

Deploying parts of the solution is a configuration management nightmare. You will end up doing it if you have millions of users connected night and day and disruption to the service would give you bad reputation. Then you do rolling updates and switch components separately. And of course carefully evolve all your interfaces to be backward compatible so it still works during the update

But for a typical corporate information system, you test the new set of components (of which some may not have changed) and deploy the new set of components as a unit. Less risk of trouble. So the coupling is not as much of a concern.

Comment: It isn't just that they know what the other parts do; it's also that they know intimate details about how those other parts go about doing whatever it is they do. It’s just like what happens when you allow yourself to become "unnaturally chummy" with some particular compiler.

Comment: @tchrist, as already said by others, it's not a yes or no, it's a scale.

Answer (score 0):

"Monolithic" is a conflated term, let's break it down:

- Monolithic binary (distribution)
- Monolithic project (all code in one place, but might be distributed in separate binaries)
- Inversion of Control (within a large project)
- Direct function calls between modules (totally valid if all modules are in your control and they will be deployed as a single binary)
- Big ball of mud - where there is no "cohesion" - this is the bad thing.

> If I need a certain part of my application to handle, say, payments, and multiple other parts to interact with the payments system, can I not leverage the abstraction features of the language I'm using (classes, access control, interfaces) to create modularization between different application functions?

You can, and you might use Inversion of Control.

For example, if I'm using Java, I could create a 'PaymentsDAO' (data access object), or maybe 'PaymentsClient', which can expose functions that the rest of the code can use to interact with the payments database, etc. If one sub-team in my team wants to work on payments, they can continue to write code in the PaymentsDAO, publish that code to the central repo, etc, while I simply use the DAO's function signatures, which would not change, and continue to write code wherever I need it, right?

> Where's the coupling?

Having Inversion of Control in a single binary works. Distributing your coupling (microservices) over network calls, and breaking up deployment of smaller binaries, risks making that coupling harder to manage. It's funny how someone can say "looser coupling" and everyone just nodes and repeats "looser coupling".

> I'm more certain about the other pros of MSA, like scalability

You might be referring to Function-as-a-service (like Lambda). They are actually optimised for low-loads, and will drain your bank account as you scale (unless you reserve capacity). Also, you shouldn't overengineer for an assumed scalability problem. A single web service with an AWS RDS database can scale quite well - you can keep adding read-only replicas too which is nice.

> flexibility of technology stacks across microservices

Make sure you use the word "polyglot" you'll feel smarter. While code bases will stratify over time, you should try to minimise the amount of languages.

> fault tolerance of a dist system

But at the expense of greater complexity, which can lead to more bugs and worse quality for your user.

> less deployment complexity

Instead of deploying a single binary, you need to have deployment pipelines for 30. I call that more complexity.

> but I'm still uncertain on coupling.

That's a great start.

Comment: ""Monolithic" is a conflated term"  I think you might mean 'overloaded' instead of 'conflated' here.  'Conflated' would indicate inappropriate use of the term..

Comment: @JimmyJames You might be right, but I was intending "ambiguous" or "confuse", where "confuse" is one of the generally accepted meanings - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflate. The primary meaning "fuse" or "converge" is also valid - where there are multiple meanings being joined into one word. I think overloaded is correct too, but I haven't used that term before.